# How to connect 2 JS files to index.html [reactjs]

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

my intention is to create a split screen html with react components. The code below is from index.html & I want to connect 2 JS files to it, one for each half of the page.

One JS file is index.js which works but a 2nd js file doesn't get rendered. index.js is id'd as "root" and the 2nd js as "root2".

```
<body>
<div class="split left">
    <div class="centered">
        <div id="root"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
    <div class="centered">
        <div id="root2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

the code I have are identical for both js files apart for getElementById('root')

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I think I'm approaching this wrong and any help would be appreciated

Comment: How are you loading the second js file?

Comment: Don’t know React good enought but i done similar stuff with Vuejs, i just created multiple instances in 1 file. <App1 /> <App2 />

Comment: @Edvin Keskin, welcome to SO. I can see you fixed your issue, please add the solution as an answer and remove it from the question!

Answer (score 1):

Having 2 renders with different id's in index.js fixed the issue, no need for 2nd js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';
import App2 from "./app2";

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App2 />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root2')
);
```